# Name and properties of $\mathrm{lcm}(\{1,\,\cdots,\,n\})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, terminology, notation

one of the most prominent functions of the first $n$ natural numbers is the factorial $n!$ that denotes their product.

Today however I wondered whether the least common multiple $\mathrm{lcm}(n):=\mathrm{lcm}(\{i\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,1\leqq i\leqq n\})$ of the first $n$ natural numbers has already been the subject of mathematical studies.
The first elements of their sequence are $1,\, 2,\, 6,\,12,\,60,\,60,\,420,\,840,\,2520,\,2520,\,27720,\, \dots$ and it is A003418 – in the **OEIS**, as Christian Bernert pointed out in his comment.

> **Questions:**
>
> - is there already an established name for $\mathrm{lcm}(n)$?
> - is there an agreed upon notation?
> - does it have an extension for non-integral complex values, analogous to the gamma function?
> - what can be said about bounds on, resp. growth-rate of the number of consecutive equal values apart from their relation to prime-gaps?

It is not hard to see that $\mathrm{lcm}(n)$ equals the *procuct of maximal prime powers less or equal n*

Comment: This is a long- and well-studied sequence and I could not believe it is not yet in OEIS. And of course it is: http://oeis.org/A003418

Comment: (Also the comments there should answer some of your questions.)

Comment: @ChristianBernert maybe because  entered it differently; I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Just a formatting thing, you already have bold **Questions** and bullet points to add emphasis, but the addition of blockquotes sort of takes away emphasis. I know people used blockquotes before add emphasis  because it put everything in a big yellow box but now it just grays the text out and moves it over a bit.

Comment: This is similar to primorial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quantity $\operatorname{lcm}(n)$ is equal to $e^{\psi (n)}$, where $\psi$ is the second [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). This function is well studied, and the prime number theorem is equivalent (indeed, usually proved using this equivalence) to the fact that $\psi (x)\sim x$.